# PHP sign in form?

Tags: php, forms

I am brand new to PHP and I just wanted to create a password form for a picture gallery online. For some reason PHP is echoing 'NO' even when I type in my set password. Please help me understand what is going wrong in my script.

```
<body>
    <div class="main-img">
        <img src="images/img/main.jpg" />
    </div><!-- END OF MAIN-img -->
    <form id="myform" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter the password" />
        <input name="button" type="submit" value="Go!" id="submit"></input>
    </form>

    <?php 
        require("other.php");
        if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
            checkpassword();
            return;
        }
    ?> 
    <div id="ask"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS MY PHP CODE:

```
<?php
function checkpassword() {
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    if($pass == "password123") {
        echo("YES");
        exit;
    } else {
        die("NO");
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: So many wrong ways of codding, but few are `1` Don't use mysql functions, `2` don't echo anything from your function, `3` don't use () for echo ....

Comment: @phpNoOBఠ_ఠ your sig grew eyes

Comment: @Orangepill That's right. I'm keeping my ఠ_ఠ on you :)

Comment: The `return;` is incorrect, remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some modifications to your code:

**HTML File:**

```
<?php 
    require("other.php");
    if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        checkpassword($pass);
    }
?>
```

**PHP File:**

```
<?php
    function checkpassword($pass) {
        if($pass == "password123") {
            echo "Yes";
            exit;
        } else {
            die("NO");
        }
    }
?>
```

See if that helps you out a little.

Comment: What's wrong with having `checkpassword` read `$_POST['password']`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not a thing. I just figured if it is in a separate file, the OP might as well make it a little more modular so it can be reused. Otherwise, the OP might as well just drop all of this inside the HTML page's PHP codeblock. You could do it your way too though. Nothing wrong with it. Just a suggestion. :)

Comment: I actually like this way better :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't check against the results for mysql_real_escape_string. This function is used when bouncing user supplied data against the database.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mysql_real_escape_string` without being connected to a database first.  You only need to use that when making database queries.

So, just do `if($_POST['password'] == 'password123')`.